# Restore Neo4j DB from Backup with Neo4J Desktop

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I have a db backup folder that I'm trying to load into a new db in Neo4J Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [neo4j-admin tool](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-backup/#restore-backup)
From Neo4j desktop, go to your database/create a new one, then open the Terminal for that database (in older versions, it was in the Manage menu, in newer versions, you'll find it in the 3 ... menu)

Once you have the terminal open, `cd bin` and follow the manual to restore